# How do I use a string in both regex Match and IsMatch?

Tags: c#, regex

Assume I have string

```
var rgx = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]\d{2}[a-zA-Z0-9](-\d{3}){2}[A-Za-z0-9]$";
```

I want to match it with a string, so I use

```
var m = Regex.Match(mystring, rgx);
if (m.Success)
 {
 \\do something
 }
```

Then somewhere else in the code I want use `rgx` as a Regex to perform a `IsMatch` operation, so I basically create a new variable

```
Regex rgx2 = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]\d{2}[a-zA-Z0-9](-\d{3}){2}[A-Za-z0-9]$");
```

Then use something like

```
rgx2.IsMatch(somestring)
```

But this does not look right...how can I do this more efficiently?

Comment: Declare the string an a constant in some class? Preferably the class that both methods are in, or in a class visible to both methods otherwise.

Comment: I would also note that there is a [non-static `Match` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx) if you are able to reuse the actual `Regex` object. But you'll need to provide more code to get a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple approach

declare the string as regex

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]\d{2}[a-zA-Z0-9](-\d{3}){2}[A-Za-z0-9]$");
```

Then do your **Match** as

```
var m = Regex.Match(mystring, rgx.ToString());
if (m.Success)
 {
 \\do something
 }
```

And your **IsMatch** check as

```
rgx.IsMatch(somestring)
```